# How do I convert a java.util.UUID to doobie.syntax.SqlInterpolator.SingleFragment?

Tags: scala, circe, http4s, doobie

I am trying to set up a simple scala app with database using doobie, http4s and circe.

How do I convert a java.util.UUID to doobie.syntax.SqlInterpolator.SingleFragment ?

```
final case class User(id: UUID, details: UserDetails)
```

```
  implicit val userDecoder: Decoder[User] = deriveDecoder[User]
  implicit def userEntityDecoder[F[_]: Sync]: EntityDecoder[F, User] = jsonOf

  implicit val userEncoder: Encoder[User] = deriveEncoder[User]
  implicit def userEntityEncoder[F[_]: Applicative]: EntityEncoder[F, User] = jsonEncoderOf

  implicit val put: Put[User] =
    Put[Json].contramap(_.asJson)

  implicit val get: Get[User] =
    Get[Json].temap(_.as[User].left.map(_.show))
```

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.12 (N/A Java 14.0.1)
[info] loading global plugins from /Users/ryan/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading settings for project bobbymoore-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /Users/ryan/fullStackRyan/bobbymoore/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to bobbymoore (in build file:/Users/ryan/fullStackRyan/bobbymoore/)
[info] sbt server started at local:///Users/ryan/.sbt/1.0/server/90f560b1e0964865fc4c/sock
sbt:bobbymoore> compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/ryan/fullStackRyan/bobbymoore/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[error] /Users/ryan/fullStackRyan/bobbymoore/src/main/scala/com/c/bobbymoore/database/UserQueries.scala:24:20: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : java.util.UUID
[error]  required: doobie.syntax.SqlInterpolator.SingleFragment
[error]          |  ${user.id},
[error]                    ^
[error] /Users/ryan/fullStackRyan/bobbymoore/src/main/scala/com/c/bobbymoore/database/UserQueries.scala:34:21: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : java.util.UUID
[error]  required: doobie.syntax.SqlInterpolator.SingleFragment
[error]          |WHERE id=$id
[error]                     ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 13 Oct 2020, 16:31:46
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL and the UUID in Java translate to UUID column in Postgres table, then you have to use a [Postgres extensions for Doobie](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/15-Extensions-PostgreSQL.html)

```
// other doobie imports
import doobie.postgres._
import doobie.postgres.implicits._

sql"""SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id = ${user.id}""".query[(UUID, String)]
```

If you don't use PSQL and this UUID maps to TEXT field you have to either map this yourself in query:

```
sql"""SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id = ${user.id.toString}"""
  .query[(String, String)]
  .map { case (uuid, name) => (UUID.fromString(uuid), name) }
```

or define your own `Meta[UUID]` instance e.g.

```
implicit val uuidMeta: Meta[UUID] =
  Meta[String].imap[UUID](UUID.fromString)(_.toString)
```

This one is needed if you want to derive an instance for e.g. case class that contains UUID. Postgres extensions library delivers one that matches PSQL implementation.

You surely *have to* define your own Meta instance if you use e.g. `Array[Byte]` or some other numeric representation on DB side to represent UUIDs.