# Use UUID in Doobie SQL update

Tags: postgresql, scala, doobie

I have the following simple (cut down for brevity) Postgres table:

```
create table users(
  id            uuid NOT NULL,
  year_of_birth smallint NOT NULL
);
```

Within a test I have seeded data.
When I run the following SQL update to correct a `year_of_birth` the error implies that I'm not providing the necessary UUID correctly.

The Doobie SQL I run is:

```
val id: String = "6ee7a37c-6f58-4c14-a66c-c17083adff81"
val correctYear: Int = 1980

sql"update users set year_of_birth = $correctYear where id = $id".update.run
```

I have tried both with and without quotes around the given $id e.g. the other version is:

```
sql"update users set year_of_birth = $correctYear where id = '$id'".update.run
```

The error upon running the above is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: have you tried using java UUID instead of String inside your code? java.util.UUID.fromString(YOUR_UUID)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64338748/how-do-i-convert-a-java-util-uuid-to-doobie-syntax-sqlinterpolator-singlefragmen) also might help

Comment: Try `id = cast($id as uuid)`

Comment: Many thanks. `cast` suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name works nicely.
I tried `UUID.fromString` but couldn't get this to work, though I shall try again.
But @AminMal also kindly pointed out the following link which does look very nice (to keep code succinct) - I'll give it a go.

Comment: Ah yes. Many thanks @AminMal - Using UUID.fromString in conjunction with the necessary Doobie implicits the following works nicely:
```
import doobie.postgres.implicits._

val id: UUID = UUID.fromString("6ee7a37c-6f58-4c14-a66c-c17083adff81")

sql"update users set year_of_birth = $correctYear where id = $id".update.run
```
Be careful with IntelliJ - It thinks that the import is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both comments provided viable solutions.

[a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) suggested the use of `cast` which works though the SQL becomes no so nice when compared to the other solution.

[AminMal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14672383/aminmal) suggested the use of available Doobie implicits which can handle a UUID within SQL and thus avoid a `cast`.

So I changed my code to the following:

```
import doobie.postgres.implicits._

val id: UUID = UUID.fromString("6ee7a37c-6f58-4c14-a66c-c17083adff81") 

sql"update users set year_of_birth = $correctYear where id = $id".update.run
```

So I'd like to mark this question as resolved because of the comment provided by [AminMal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14672383/aminmal)

Comment: How do I "mark best answer" from @AminMal?

Comment: They need to post it as an answer for you to be able to do that. If they do, you can mark it as the answer